# ASP MVC Sitemap is there an Image HTML Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I have an ASP MVC Sitemap which look something like this

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" imageUrl="home.png" controller="Home" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Search" controller="Search" imageUrl="magnifying_glass.png" action="Index">
```

The nodes all have an 'imageUrl' property assigned to them which I would like to access within my view. I know there is a SiteMap helper included within the library which allows me to the get the title via

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapTitle()
```

However, I can't see any way of obtaining the imgUrl. Before I write my own, does anybody know if this already exists? I've search around but can't find any way of doing it within the existing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've just written something myself. It's very simple.

```
public static class MvcSiteMapImageUrlHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString SiteMapImageUrl(this MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper)
        {
            var node = helper.Provider.CurrentNode;

            if (node != null)
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString(node["ImageUrl"]);
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```